Does the U.S. Supreme Court have unlimited ability to interpret the Constitution?
Is there any legal mechanism stopping a Supreme Court justice from concocting any interpretation of law they want, no matter how outlandish?
What are the de facto buffers against this? Can the other judges vote a judge out of the court? Or a President dismiss a judge?
Is the main idea that if a society doesn’t align with a judge’s choices, there are in reality societal feedback mechanisms which could constrain the influence of that judge? (For example, at minimum, in the next presidential election cycle, a different president getting elected?)

Also, questions about de facto proteccions would be better suited for [politics.se].

Any US civics textbook will have a chapter on "checks and balances", and you're basically asking about the checks on the judicial branch.

Yes, they have carte Blanc to interprete the law as they wish.
The sole course of action to prevent supreme Court judicial misconduct is for the House to impeach the judges and the Senate to convict and remove them.
A president cannot remove a judge. Even if a crime was committed outside of judicial immunity, the judge arrested convicted and sentence, only an act of Congress can remove an Article III judge, under the modern interpretation of the good behavior clause.

That's really not true that it's "carte blanc[che]". There are a number of mechanisms the other branches can use as a check on a runaway Court. Removing appellate jurisdiction, court packing, and impeachment/removal all immediately come to mind. None have been used but they have been threatened. Specifically the threat of court packing ended the Lochner era (which was pretty much a runaway Court) and forced them to come to their senses. That's really the whole point of checks and balances. No one truly has "carte blanche" in our government.
